# CSV export from BigQuery to Google Cloud Storage

Tags: csv, google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage, export

A few days ago I did a table export from BQ to GCS in CSV format and it had worked
For a few days, I have not been able to do this export, the procedure is well launched but I have no file in GCS even after several hours of waiting.
Any idea?

I open my table, then I click on the export button, choose "export to GCS".
In the pop-up window on the right, I select the folder in my GCS bucket, and save. The message 'export "table_name" launched' is on the screen after that. So it seems OK from this side.

The previous times, I was able to find my CSV file in the right GCS folder quite quickly (30s for a 1 GB file). But today, nothing appears in this folder even after several hours.

Comment: I think the export is asynchronous. Review Cloud Logging for entries that might indicate the error.

Comment: I found errors in the log: "too large to be exported to a single file"

Comment: Thanks for your advice. But it would still be better to have a pop-up directly in the BQ window...

Comment: Indeed, there is a limit to the single file export size (1 GB, mine was 1.04 GB...).
I don't know if it can be done faster, but I proceeded as follows:
-I exported the file in several files (this way: name*.csv).
-I got 24 different files in GCS (of which 4 only had the header line so I deleted them).
-I recreated 20 tables in BG with the remaining files, I merged them with UNION ALL
-I exported this new table in GCS to finally obtain an 877 MB file.